# Codeigniter Paginaton Next button is not working

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to display information from database. I have set $config['per_page'] to  2, in my view file I can see the information I want but when I click on the next button it doesn't change anything. The database values remain same and the current page remains the first page too.

Would you please kindly help me figure out the problem?

Thanks in Advance :)

Controller:

```
 function index($id){                   
    $this->load->library('pagination');                                 
    $config['base_url'] = site_url().'Student_fee_status/index/'.$id;

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('studentpayment1');
    $this->db->where('studentid', $id); 

    $query = $this->db->get('');
    $numrows=$query->num_rows();                    

    $config['total_rows'] = $numrows;
    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $config['uri_segment'] = '2'; 
    $config['num_links'] = 20;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination" align="center">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);                 
    $this->load->model('Mod_student_fee_status');

    $data['records']= $this->Mod_student_fee_status->fee_status($id,$config['per_page'],$config['uri_segment']);
    $data['main_content']='view_student_fee_status';

    $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);                   
}
```

My Model :

```
function fee_status($id,$perPage,$uri_segment) { 
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('studentpayment1');
    $this->db->where('studentid', $id); 

    $getData = $this->db->get('', $perPage, $uri_segment);

    if($getData->num_rows() > 0)
        return $getData->result_array();
    else
        return null;
}
```

## EDIT

When the page first loads the link looks like this- http://localhost/sundial/Student_fee_status/index/1006/
but when I click on the next page it looks like this- http://localhost/sundial/Student_fee_status/index/1006/2

My View File:

```
<h1>Payment Status</h1>     
<?php if(count($records) > 0) { ?>
    <table id="table1" class="gtable sortable">
        <thead>
            <tr> 
                <th>S.N</th>
                <th>Invoice ID</th>
                <th>Transaction Description</th>
                <th>Received Date</th>
                <th>Debit</th>
                <th>Credit</th>
                <th>Balance</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    <?php $i = $this->uri->segment(2) + 0; foreach ($records as $row){ $i++; ?>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                $mydate= $row['period'];
                $month = date("F",strtotime($mydate));
                $year = date("Y",strtotime($mydate));
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $i; ?>.</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['invoiceid'];?></td>
                <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>student_fee_status/fee_types/<?php echo $row['paymentid']; ?>" rel="1" class="newWindow" >Total Fee For <?php echo $month ;?>, <?php echo $year ;?>  </a></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['received_date'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['totalamount'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo "0";?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['totalamount'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $i; ?>.</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['invoiceid'];?></td>
                <td>Payment Received </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['received_date'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo "0";?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['amountpaid'];?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        $balance=$row['totalamount']-$row['amountpaid']; 
                        if($balance>0){
                            echo "<font color=\"red\">$balance</font>";
                        }
                        else {
                            echo $balance;
                        }
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php } ?>

<div class="tablefooter clearfix">
    <div class="pagination">
        <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?> 
    </div>                              
</div>
```

Comment: what does the link look like?

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your view too.

Comment: Thanks both of you.. chaft and  Gustav Bertram for your reply. Please check the edited part of my post above.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we won't be able to see the pages you serve off localhost. Try putting their source on pastebin, or make them available publicly.

Comment: I have put the codes on Pastebin.. For Controller: http://pastebin.com/1B7VKFbZ   Model: http://pastebin.com/fwRkT3DC View: http://pastebin.com/D7gcHCV2     Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are telling the pagination library to use `$config['uri_segment'] = '2';` - the second segment of your uri.

When this is your url: http://localhost/sundial/Student_fee_status/index/1006/ I am guessing this is your base_url: http://localhost/sundial/

In this case your segments are:

1. Student_fee_status - your controller
2. index - the controllers method you are calling
3. 1006 - the argument you are calling the controllers method with
4. this should be the argument for pagination

Try this

`$config['uri_segment'] = '4';`

instead of

`$config['uri_segment'] = '2';`

**edit**:

```
$data['records']= $this->Mod_student_fee_status->fee_status($id,$config['per_page'],$config['uri_segment']);
```

I think this line contains another error.

You pass your model the information which uri_segment is used by the pagination library. That should be 4 now. However, your model uses this value to specify an offset in your query. This means you always put an offset of 4 into your query. But I think what you really want to do is, pass the model the VALUE of the 4th uri_segment.

I would try this instead:

```
 $data['records']= $this->Mod_student_fee_status->fee_status($id,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']));
```

Comment: Sorry walfish3d, I thought your suggestion worked for me but after a while I figured it out that the next button is working but the database values of the first page is not changing. Do you have any idea what is wrong with my code? Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Thank you very very much walfish3d. Its working just the way I wanted. I have been trying to fix this for two days. You are great man...:)

Comment: glad I could help. I had basically the same errors on my first try with the pagination library :)